# Permission system not working as expected

Tags: permissions, acl, roles

I created a simple permission structure where a group of CiviCRM users ("Group A") has write access to a group of contacts ("Group B"). (Every logged in user has read access.)

When a contact is now added to "Group B", users of "Group A" see the edit button on the contact and can add/remove the contact to/from groups on the contact detail page. When removing the contact from "Group B", the edit button disappears. So far, everything as expected.

But when using the actions menu from the search results, users can add/remove group assignments of a contact which is not in "Group B".

Isn't this an inconsistency in the permission system? Or am I missing something? How to avoid group membership changes of contacts which are not in "Group B" by users which are in "Group A"?

I'm using the newest CiviCRM version 5.63.1 under WordPress.

Comment: So users in group A are permitted to see contacts that are not in group B? i.e. they can see contacts in group C?

Comment: Yes, every logged in user has read access to all contacts.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is quite possible that the bulk group add and remove doesn't implement ACLs, which should prevent this. If you can replicate the issue on the [wpmaster demo](https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/), then you should post an issue on [Gitlab](https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues).

Comment: Thanks. I created an [issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4432) on Gitlab.